# Executing post-build step Intellij IDEA CE 2020.3?

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I am using IntelliJ IDEA CE 2020.3 to build a simple JAR file. After the build, I'd like to copy the created JAR to a library directory.

I am using the Ant plugin that comes bundled with the IDE. I can't seem to find the underlying Ant build/control files that make the whole thing work. I assume Ant uses the .XML files that are part of the IDE's project settings, but this is unclear.

In any case, is there a way to add the "copy" step that I mention above?
Do I have to either use the built-in Ant or take it over completely myself?
Can I edit the default that ships with the IDE?

Comment: Don't you see `build.xml` in the project? I would go with ant solution and you can call any ant task from IDE. You can also add custom build step in IDE and configure external tool, but it will work only in IDE.

Comment: When I create the project, I simply choose a standard Java application (vs. Maven, for example). There is no build.xml anywhere. The standard build seems to use some sort of built-in Ant configuration. So, I'd like to either configure/change the built-in one, somehow augment it or add a custom build step in the IDE. I couldn't find any way to add a custom build step that wasn't related to Ant. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the standart java project doesn't use ant at all. IDE just executes commands to compile and maybe package classes to jar.

Comment: I think it does use Ant because the build window reports Ant output. I just ran a "standard" fresh IDE project and these are a few of the lines that were output... Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Running 'before' tasks

Answer (score 0):

All,

So after some experimenting, I found that if I manually create the **build.xml** file, I can execute post-build steps. For my example here, I created the following, simple **build.xml** and added it to the top-level IntelliJ project directory (where the .iml file lives):

**build.xml** (manually created)

```
<project name="mylib" default="copy-file">
    <target name="copy-file">
        <copy file="out/artifacts/mylib_JAR/mylib.jar" tofile = "./mylib.jar" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Note that the directories are relative to the project directory.

IntelliJ IDEA enabled me to add the copy-file task to augment the default, built-in build. To configure your tasks via the IDE, open the Ant tool window via the *View/Tool Windows/Ant* main menu item.

I hope this helps someone out there!